# What does this mathematical expression mean?

Tags: education

I am reading a natural language processing paper and I came across this expression. I don't know what it means. Especially the unif part.

$$m_i \sim \operatorname{unif}\{1,n\}\text{ for } i = 1 \text{ to } k$$

Comment: Well, it very well may mean the "uniform distribution."  Hard to tell from what's here, but if the distrubution is discrete, each of these are equally probable:  $\{ 1,2,3,\cdots, n\}$.

Comment: Since you are asking about the meaning of an expression found in "a natural language processing paper", it is essential that you give a citation of that paper.  While one may suspect the notation describes a "uniform distribution" on a set, the paper itself will be best evidence of what the author intended.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.10555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you have $k$ random variables, $m_1, m_2, \ldots , m_k$, each of which was chosen from a uniform distribution with extreme values $1$ and $n$.  It is fundamentally ambiguous as to whether the distribution is discrete or continuous.  (Check your source.)

Example:  if $k = 3$ and $n = 5$, you could have...

...in the continuous case:

$m_1 = 2.938, m_2 = 1.155, m_3 = 4.076$.

... and in discrete case:

$m_1 = 4, m_2 = 5, m_3 = 1$.

Given your source is about natural language processing having (discrete) words, I suspect (but don't know) that the latter is the case.

Comment: Rather than "bounded by $1$ and $n$", I'd say it's a uniform distribution on the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n-1,n\},$ which means every member of that set has the same probability $1/n. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also think they are discrete.